# Is dividend factored into Annualized return?

Tags: mutual-funds, dividends, index-fund, vanguard

I would like to keep it as simple as possible. If I visit Vanguard Benchmark returns page here

https://personal.vanguard.com/us/funds/tools/benchmarkreturns

It shows annualized returns for different funds for up to a decade. Now for example, S&P 500 Index it shows that it has returned 7.31% for last 10 years. Now, I know that average yield on this fund is around 1.90%. Is it factored into the annualized reutun when Vanguard reports it? If not, would it be safe to say that in fact the return was 7.31% + 1.90%?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that link shows returns for an index and not a fund! Note at the bottom:

> Index performance is provided as a benchmark. It is not illustrative
>   of any particular investment. An investment cannot be made in an
>   index.

What format would you expect the dividends to actually be handled as some old Unit Investment Trusts would just collect the dividends as cash while some mutual funds may re-invest the proceeds right away? [The Handbook of Financial Instruments](https://books.google.ca/books?id=R7YGTqsLVCYC&pg=PA535&lpg=PA535&dq=SPDR%20dividend%20drag&source=bl&ots=MhgbfOmXyr&sig=RMeBMc5PNR95PcYa-JbC_koKx5E&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLypm2tazKAhVE-GMKHcz_CHMQ6AEIMTAE#v=onepage&q=SPDR%20dividend%20drag&f=false) has this part on page 539:

> The dividends must be retained as cash and invested, in effect in
>   money market instruments until the dividend payment is made.

Thus, while you may think your question is simple there are more than a few ways to go. [M*](http://www.morningstar.com/invglossary/annual_returns.aspx) has this:

> Annual total returns are calculated on a calendar-year and
>   year-to-date basis. Total return includes both capital appreciation
>   and dividends. The year-to-date return is updated daily.
>
> For mutual funds, return includes both income (in the form of
>   dividends or interest payments) and capital gains or losses (the
>   increase or decrease in the value of a security).
>
> Morningstar calculates total return by taking the change in a fund's
>   NAV, assuming the reinvestment of all income and capital gains
>   distributions (on the actual reinvestment date used by the fund)
>   during the period, and then dividing by the initial NAV. Unless marked
>   as load-adjusted total returns, Morningstar does not adjust total
>   return for sales charges or for redemption fees.
>
> Total returns do account for management, administrative, and 12b-1
>   fees and other costs automatically deducted from fund assets.